# Using a link's id to parse data from an xml file with jquery

Tags: jquery, xml, ajax

the xml is like this

```
<post id="1">
  <content>...</content>
</post>
<post id="2">
  <content>...</content>
</post>
<post id="3">
  <content>...</content>
</post>
```

and then the html is

```
<div id="content"></div>
<a id="1">option 1</a>
<a id="2">option 2</a>
<a id="3">option 3</a>
```

I'm trying (and failing) to replace whatever's in the div with the 'content' of a post when you click on its corresponding link- and the ids are not always numbers. I think I need to use event.target.id but can't find info on this anywhere on the web, thanks for your help.

Comment: btw ID's shouldn't start with a digit

Comment: dw, they're all actually words, it was just easier to display what I meant :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
$('#content a').click(function() {
    var id = this.id;
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "xml_file.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(xml) {
            $('#'+id).html(xml.find('#'+id).html());
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

This should replace all html content from with in a `<post id="X">` and place it inside #content when `<a id="X">` is clicked.

also don't forget to return false to prevent the default action of `<a>`

Answer (score 3):

```
$('a').click(function() {
    var id = this.id;
    $.get("http://www.foo.com/xmlfile.xml", function(xml) {
        var content = $(xml).find('post#' + id + ' content').text();
        $('#content').html(content);
    });
});
```